# Babel causes document.write to break CSS in Stack Snippets

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

I know that `document.write` is bad,¹ but this is terribly inconsistent and doesn't make much sense.

```js
document.write("babel: false");
```

```css
*:after {
  content: "it works";
}
```

```js
document.write("babel: true");
```

```css
*:after {
  content: "it works";
}
```

---

¹: An understatement¹ precedes this.